# How can i configure ag-grid to show on the last page empty row to fill it?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I have ag-grid with height and pagination and on last page i have big blank space (presented on example image). I would like to have this blank space to be filled with empty styled rows. Maybe someone have idea how to do this?

It should be only visual element. That dummy rows can not have impact to real data. Is only for vanish that big blank space, to make it a little prettier.

[image: example image)]

Comment: Need some more details... these extra rows need to be valid records that users can edit for example? Are these dummy records supposed to be displayed in the total count?

Comment: It should be only visual element. That dummy rows can not have impact to real data. Is only for vanish that big blank space, to make it a little prettier.

Comment: In that case, I think you should just apply a background to the grid viewport using CSS.